# Probability of Getting at least a pair of cards

Tags: probability

say you have green cards numbered from one up to three thousand and yellow ones numbered the same way.
What is the prob of getting at least one pair if you draw four cards randomly?
i think :
$$
1-\frac{\binom{3000}{4}2^4}{\binom{6000}{4}} => 0.00100...
$$
It is correct?
Thanks

Comment: Please define "pair".

Comment: By "pair", do you mean one green and one yellow card with the same number?

Comment: yes, one green and one yellow card with the same number.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever card you first draw, the probability the second does not match is $\frac{5998}{5999}$. Given the second did not match, the probability the third does not match either of the first two is $\frac{5996}{5998}$. And given no matches among the first three cards, the probability of no match on the fourth is $\frac{5994}{5997}$. Multiply. If the result is $p$, our answer is $1-p$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: You are welcome. Of course the answer is the same as yours, I wanted to do in a less combinatorial way.

Answer (score 0):

$\checkmark$ This is correct.

You have 1 minus the probability of selecting four different faces of either suit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer